# Accessing web service in oracle 10g pl/sql procedures

Tags: web-services, oracle, oracle10g, plsqldeveloper

I’m using soap_api method for accessing web services in oracle. When I create add_numbers function and I execute add_numbers function then Function doesn’t execute.
 fires following error when calling web service in select statement

```
select add_numbers(2,5) from dual
```

error is

- ORA-29273: HTTP request failed
- ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP",line 1029
- ORA-12541: TNS:no listener
- ORA-06512: at "dbtest.SOAP_API",line 144
- ORA-06512: at "dbtest.ADD_NUMBERS", line 34  FROM!

I’m using this function and soap_api methods from this link. taken example from
http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/9i/consuming-web-services-9i.php#Top

Function for calling web services.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_numbers (p_int_1 IN  NUMBER,  p_int_2  IN  NUMBER)  RETURN NUMBER AS
  l_request   soap_api.t_request;
  l_response  soap_api.t_response;
  l_return    VARCHAR2(32767);  
  l_url          VARCHAR2(32767);
  l_namespace    VARCHAR2(32767);
  l_method       VARCHAR2(32767);
  l_soap_action  VARCHAR2(32767);
  l_result_name  VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
  l_url         := 'http://192.168.0.75:9001/LicWebService.asmx';
  l_namespace   := 'xmlns="http://192.168.0.75:9001/"';
  l_method      := 'AddNum';
  l_soap_action := 'http://192.168.0.75:9001/AddNum';
  l_result_name := 'return';  
  l_request := soap_api.new_request(p_method => l_method,   p_namespace=> l_namespace);
  soap_api.add_parameter(p_request => l_request,p_name => 'int1',p_type => 'xsd:integer',p_value   => p_int_1);
  soap_api.add_parameter(p_request => l_request,p_name=> 'int2', p_type=> 'xsd:integer',p_value   => p_int_2);
  l_response := soap_api.invoke(p_request => l_request, p_url=> l_url,  p_action => l_soap_action);
  l_return := soap_api.get_return_value(p_response  => l_response,p_name=> l_result_name, p_namespace => NULL);
END;
```

Kindly suggest me where i am making mistake.

Comment: I am pretty sure that your problem was that Oracle did not process the port 9001 correctly. Did you figure out what was the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Either your TNS is not set up properly or the TNS service is not running. This is the reason why the `UTL_HTTP` api isn't working (which is used by `SOAP_API`).

Follow [this](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_12541_tns_no_listener.htm) link to troubleshoot and resolve this.

Comment: hi Annjawn, thanks for reply,
 but when i am accessing a demo web service in my application which is hosted, i able to access
 but when i trying to access web service from my localhost i am not able to access.
 this means there is no problem in configuration at my oracle server end, because i am able to access other  web service,
Please suggest

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/997587